# Integral Ring Extension induces Surjection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\phi:R \subset A$ an integral ring extension.

I want to know why and how to see that in this case the induced morphism $f_{\phi}: \operatorname{Spec}(A) \to \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is surjective.

Comment: This is the so-called "Lying Over" property. A sketch of the proof is this: (i) A prime lying over a maximal ideal in an integral extension is maximal. (ii) Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal of $R$ and localize at the multiplicative set $T=R\setminus\mathfrak p$ to get $R_{\mathfrak p}\to A_T$. Now choose a maximal ideal of $A_T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical proof goes along these lines:

We need a lemma:

> **Lemma**: Let $A$ be an integral domain, $R$ be a subring such that $A$ is integral over $R$. The  $A$ is a field if and only if $R$ is.

Suppose first $R$ is *local* ring, with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ , and consider any maximal ideal $\mathfrak n$ of $A$. As $R/\mathfrak n\cap R \hookrightarrow A/\mathfrak n\;$ is injective, the above lemma shows $\mathfrak n\cap R\;$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, hence
$$\mathfrak n\cap R=\mathfrak m,$$
i.e. the maximal ideal ideal of $R$ lifts to $\operatorname{Max} A \subset\operatorname{Spec} A$.

Now for the general case: let $\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Spec}R$, localise at $\mathfrak p$ and consider the commutative diagram:
\begin{alignat}{2}
R_{\phantom{\mathfrak p}}& \hookrightarrow& A_{\phantom{\mathfrak p}}\\
\downarrow_{\phantom{\mathfrak p}}&&\downarrow_{\phantom{\mathfrak p}}\\
R_{\mathfrak p}& \hookrightarrow&\; A_{\mathfrak p}
\end{alignat}
By the *local* case, $\mathfrak p R_{\mathfrak p}$ lifts to a maximal ideal $\mathfrak n $ in $A_{\mathfrak p}$. This ideal is the localisation $\mathfrak q_{\mathfrak p}$ of a prime ideal $\mathfrak q\in\operatorname{Spec} A$, and, since  the inverse image of $\mathfrak n =\mathfrak q_{\mathfrak p}$ in $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is  $\mathfrak p R_{\mathfrak p}$, hence its inverse image in $R$ is $\mathfrak p$, the inverse image of $\mathfrak q$ in $R$ by the upper map is also $\mathfrak p$.